# HTML Email Builds - Using long blocks of text in image alt attribute

Tags: html, email, html-email, alt

I have written up a beautiful email template and everything is going swimmingly - except my alt text.

The images I have labelled with short alt text are working fine.

The images where I have placed paragraphs of text in just do not show (this is probably due to it overflowing the box).

I used to work in an email marketing company and I'm sure I remember being able to use a long block of text in an alt attribute.

I have tried applying using inline styles a small font-size, line-height and white-space:pre. I have also broken my text up onto multiple lines. All having no effect.

Can a litmus legend share their wealth of knowledge and help me get the longer blocks of alt text showing too?

Here is an example of my insanity:

```
<tr>
<td width="640" align="center" valign="top">
    <img src="/email/241018/infographic_02.png" class="full-width" alt="DIGITAL | Using a range of programming languages,
    we build digital platforms that often act as a 
    campaign hub for our clients’ marketing efforts. 
    This ranges from bespoke informational websites 
    profiling more than 1000 products through to 
    more concise microsites developed as a knowledge 
    hub for a campaign as well as tailored product 
    and informational apps designed to appeal to 
    specific target groups. Email marketing, webinars 
    and digital surveys are further digital tools 
    which we implement on behalf of our clients. 
    As well as building sites we also utilise 
    search engine optimisation techniques to ensure 
    that our client’s websites are reaching optimum 
    performance." width="640" height="287" border="0" style="display:block; font-size: 12px; line-height: 14px; white-space:pre;"></a>
</td>
```

Thanks, Jason.

Comment: I'm trying this in chromium and firefox, and I can't reproduce; when the image doesn't load, the size of the image stretches to fit the alt text. This is likely browser dependent behaviour, what browser are you using?

Comment: This is for email clients primarily. - Outlook

Answer (score 1):

If the length of your alt text is greater than the width of your image then the text will not be displayed in the majority of email clients. I don't think there is any way around this.

Alternative options could be to use a background image and overlay the copy as live text or shorten the alt text to be more descriptive of the image rather than directly replacing a copy block.